# Uncaught Error when using the right selector in JQuery to indicate a HTML table and use a Bootstrap-table function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, jquery-selectors, getjson, bootstrap-table

I have a table inside a div in my Index.cshtml page (Asp.Net core)

```
<div id="tbldiv">
    <table 
           id="tblCampaign"
           class="table"
           data-toggle="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="name" scope="col">Name</th>
                <th data-field="country">Country</th>
                <th data-field="totalBudget">Total Budget</th>
                <th data-field="dailyBudget">Daily Budget</th>
                <th data-field="model">Model</th>
                <th data-field="payout">Payout</th>
                <th data-field="status">Status</th>
                <th data-field="link">Link</th>
                <th data-field="advertiserID">Advertiser ID</th>
            </tr>   
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to populate my table using Bootstrap table.
Here's my site.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('Index').ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('Index?handler=ListCampaigns', function (data) {
            $("#tblCampaign").bootstrapTable({
                columns: data
            });
        }); 
    });
});
```

My OnGetListCampaign() in Index.cshtml.cs:

```
        public JsonResult OnGetListCampaigns()
        {
            var jsonCampaigns = CampaignManager.GetCampaignsTest();
            return new JsonResult(jsonCampaigns);
        }
```

Which Select from SQL database and return a List of my Item.

Here's my problem:
When I run it, it complains about the selector in site.js if I understood the problem, I used $("#tblCampaign") for  and it should be right to select the Id using #

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div class="bootstrap-table bootstrap4">
      <div class="fixed-table-toolbar"></div>
      
      <div class="fixed-table-container">
      <div class="fixed-table-header"><table></table></div>
      <div class="fixed-table-body">
      <div class="fixed-table-loading">
      <span class="loading-wrap">
      <span class="loading-text">Loading, please wait</span>
      <span class="animation-wrap"><span class="animation-dot"></span></span>
      </span>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fixed-table-footer"><table><thead><tr></tr></thead></table></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fixed-table-pagination"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I think its `$(document)`, in jQuery everything in the parentheses have to be between `quotes` or `double quotes`, though `id` should start with `#` and `class` with a dot. so I suppose changing it to `$("document")` might hopefully solve the issue

Comment: and if `index` is a tag name leave it alone but if it is a class name or id just add # or dot accordingly.

Comment: Does your developer debug console report errors or other information?